# Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC batch update

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

I am trying to persist these two classes in oracle database using hibernate annotations and I am getting these errors.

I have two other classes which are the same and I am able to add them to the database, but this one is getting these errors.

Event Class:

```
package Q3;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CollectionTable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="events")
public class Event {
@Id
@Column(name="e_id" ,unique=true,nullable=false)
private int e_id;

@Column(name="event_name")
String event_name;

@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="feedbacks",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="event_id"))
@Column(name="feed")
private Set<String> feedback;

public Event(int event_id, String event_name) {
    super();
    this.e_id = event_id;
    this.event_name = event_name;
}
public int getEvent_id() {
    return e_id;
}
public void setEvent_id(int event_id) {
    this.e_id = event_id;
}
public String getEvent_name() {
    return event_name;
}
public void setEvent_name(String event_name) {
    this.event_name = event_name;
}
public Set<String> getFeedback() {
    return feedback;
}
public void setFeedback(Set<String> feedback) {
    this.feedback = feedback;
}




}
```

### **Feedback Class**

```
package Q3;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="feedbacks")
public class Feedback {

    @Id
    @Column(name="f_id",unique=true,nullable=false)
    private int f_id;
    @Column(name="feedback")
    private String feedback;

    @Column(name="event_id")
    private int event_id;


    public Feedback(int f_id, String feedback, int event_id) {
        super();
        this.f_id = f_id;
        this.feedback = feedback;
        this.event_id = event_id;
    }
    public int getF_id() {
        return f_id;
    }
    public void setF_id(int f_id) {
        this.f_id = f_id;
    }
    public String getFeedback() {
        return feedback;
    }
    public void setFeedback(String feedback) {
        this.feedback = feedback;
    }
    public int getEvent_id() {
        return event_id;
    }
    public void setEvent_id(int event_id) {
        this.event_id = event_id;
    }

}
```

EventMain Class

```
package Q3;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

public class EventMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfiguration config=new AnnotationConfiguration();
        SessionFactory sf=config.configure
                ("hibernate1.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
        Session ses=sf.openSession();
        Transaction tx=ses.beginTransaction();
        ses.beginTransaction();
        Feedback feed=new Feedback(1, "It was a good event. I enjoyed it a lot.", 1);
        Event e=new Event(1, "WWF");
        ses.save(e);
        ses.save(feed);


        tx.commit();

        ses.close();


    }

}
```

Error

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Hibernate: insert into events (event_name, e_id) values (?, ?)
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareBatchStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2395)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2858)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1206)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:137)
    at Q3.EventMain.main(EventMain.java:23)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwBatchUpdateException(DatabaseError.java:343)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10657)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    ... 15 more
```

This is the config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
            oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
            jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:ORCL
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
            hr
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
            hr
        </property>
        <property name="show_sql">
            true
        </property>
        <property name="dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">
            update
        </property> 
        <mapping class="Q3.Event"></mapping>
        <mapping class="Q3.Feedback"></mapping>
        <mapping class="Q2.Product"></mapping>
        <mapping class="NEw.College"></mapping>
        <mapping class="NEw.Student"></mapping>

    </session-factory>    

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: try to add default constructor for `Feedback`

Comment: This error clearly tells that the `feedbacks` table is not present :`ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`